# Silverlight vs asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Can any one tell me if i want to learn silverlight is it neceesary to have some knowledge of asp.net?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all its not silverlight vs asp.net. Those two are entirely different.

> Silverlight is a cross-browser,
>   cross-platform implementation of the
>   .NET Framework for building Rich
>   Interactive Applications(RIA) for the
>   web.They execute from the web browser itself.

You can use any server side technology along with silverlight.

See

[Server-side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting)

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply.What i know about is silverlight is web-browser side and asp.net is serverside.If want to develop applications which uses server side then asp.net knowledge is required.
is it correct?

Comment: No you can use other languages like Java to develop web applications

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is a client-side technology that talks to services - web services, WS-*, WCF, RSS, Restful interfaces, etc. It has no dependencies on any specific server technology. Silverlight also has a JavaScript bridge, so it can use JavaScript to communicate with other components of a web page.

On the other hand, Silverlight is a client-side implementation of .NET's run-time and a subset of the .NET framework, so as you learn Silverlight, there is some positive knowledge transfer between .NET server-side and Silverlight development.